SP-API Returning Empty Shipment
Context
I am currently using the Amazon Selling Partner Fulfillment Inbound API v2024-03-20 to retrieve shipment data for past and current shipments, which I need to present to a client. After reading the documentation, I have made the following API calls:

GET: /inbound/fba/2024-03-20/inboundPlans/

This endpoint returns a list of Inbound Plans.


GET: /inbound/fba/2024-03-20/inboundPlans/{Inbound Plan ID}/placementOptions

Using the Inbound Plan ID obtained from the previous call, I make a request to this endpoint to retrieve placement options.



Problem
The placementOptions endpoint is returning empty data, even though I expect the data to exist. I have seen discussions in other forums where users have successfully retrieved data using the now-deprecated getShipments endpoint from version 0, but I am unable to retrieve any data with the new endpoints.
I suspect that I might be misinterpreting the API flow or missing a crucial step in the process. I would greatly appreciate if someone with knowledge/expertise in these specific API endpoints could point out where I might be going wrong in my approach and confirm if I am following the correct flow.
